# fdisk -l doesn't show start sector

Tags: files, mount, fdisk

I must mount the .img file.
So I try to follow this link https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-mount-img-file-882386/.
But there is a problem.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l ./rootfs_ubuntu_18_04.img 
    Disk ./rootfs_ubuntu_18_04.img: 5 GiB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

It doesn't show start block of the file.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a partitioned disk image, so there are no partitions to list. From its name I'd guess it's the root filesystem of an Ubuntu system, in which case you just mount it

```
mkdir -p /mnt/img
mount rootfs_ubuntu_18_04.img /mnt/img
```

The image will be mounted on `/mnt/img`